# How to composer update a github repo

Tags: github, version-control, composer-php

I recently gain administration of a Github repo, on my developing server we use composer, im trying to do a `composer update`, in `composer.json` i have defined the repo as VCS type pointing to my github repo.

I commit and push some changes to the repo, but when i do composer update it says *there is nothing to update*. Other than the commit and the push, there is something else i need to do in order to allow composer to see there is an update in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your repo is https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Web .

You do commit and push updating the repo for the changes.

Composer is a tool to manage the dependencies for a project. So say if you are using this package downloaded via composer, like

`composer.json`

```
{
    "require": {
         "aura/web": "2.0.*@beta"
    }
}
```

and

```
$ php composer.phar update
```

You will get the latest version. In order for composer to understand it is updated, you need to first add the package in packagist.org . What you need to do is activate the service hook in `https://github.com/<user/org>/<repo-name>/settings/hooks` .

You can get more information from respective websites

[Packagist](https://packagist.org)

[Composer](https://getcomposer.org/)

For a quick start read http://www.sitepoint.com/php-dependency-management-with-composer/ , there will be many if you search in google.

Answer (score -1):

You only specify your repo URL and it will automatically scan your composer.json for package info. Keep in mind that repositories have a higher priority over Packagist when installing or updating.

The template used regularly in various projects is as follows:

```
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type":"package",
      "package": {
        "name": "package-name",
        "version":"master",
        "type": "wordpress-plugin",
        "source": {
          "type": "git",
          "url": "https://github.com/package-name.git",
          "reference":"master"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "package-name": "dev-master"
  }
```